# form falls out of div in IE compatibility mode

Tags: css, internet-explorer, positioning, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a from inside a div (with a border). This looks good on Firefox and IE 10 (not sure about older versions of IE). However, sometimes IE activates the compatibility mode and then the form (input box and submit button) fall out of the div. Is there some css tweak to prevent this?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="box">
       <h2 style="display:inline;">Some sample text</h2>

      <form id="frm">
        <input type="text" id="tb" />
        <input type="submit" class="button" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and my css

```
.box {
  display:block;
  height:40px;
  magin-left:5px;
  padding:5px 0 0 10px;
  width:740px;
  background:green;
  border:1px solid black;
}
h2 {
  margin:0 0 7px;
  padding:0;
  font:1.6em Arial;
  letter-spacing: -1px
}
#tb {
  width:225px
}
.button {
  float:right;
  width:93px;
  margin-left:5px;
  padding:2px 0
}
form {
  float:right;
}
#frm {
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-top:2px;
  width:330px;
}
```

Live example at jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/d3EdW/1/

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Since your form is floated, try clearing it by putting `overflow: auto;` on a parent of the form, such as `.box`.

Comment: That just hides the form (or the parts of the form that are outside the div). But I want it to look the same with or without compatibility mode

Comment: overflow: auto doesn't always hide content; it lets the browser choose whether to add scrollbars or hide content if the content is wider than the container.  It's a pretty cool way of clearing floats. Maybe I misunderstand what "falling out" looks like - can you post a screenshot?

Comment: +1 @KatieK's solution is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/d3EdW/4/show

Comment: I added a screenshot in my original post. As you can see the inputbox and submit button are not inside the green area. In FF and without the comp. mode, they are.

Comment: @Nin Also, sites only appear in compat view if they're on Microsoft's Compat View List, of if you've personally added them in your local browser.